spring-data-mongodb : cannot find symbol class QPerson
I encountered the following error while fetching the spring-data-mongodb GitHub repository and running the tests. How can I resolve this issue?
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb.git
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class QPerson
  location: class org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.AbstractPersonRepositoryIntegrationTests[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/M8kCbPpB.png)

I pulled the latest repository from the main branch and also ran mvn clean test-compile.
